# Sharing Angular-Resource instances across entire application

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have a simple resource of categories, with a cached `query` action:

```
app.factory 'Category', ($resource) ->
 $resource "/categories/:id", {id: '@id'}, {
   query: { cache: true, isArray: true, method: 'GET' }
 }
```

I have multiple controllers/directives that call `Category.query()` to get all categories. The request is cached so it doesn't execute multiple HTTP requests, which is fine, but turns out that `angular-resource` returns different Category instances every time. If I edit one category on a directive it doesn't update the rest, simply because it's not the same instance.

*** My Question: What's the recommended way to share all the instances of a query between all callers when using `angular-resource`? ***

My current solution is ugly: I override the query method, call the request only once, cache the result in a variable, and preserve all the callbacks in an array, then call them at once when the request is done. It's ugly but it works.

Gist of the code: https://gist.github.com/elado/a6f5f1f8edade63a3b9d

I tried `angular-cached-resource` but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is
`$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);`

which registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.

Here is the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Answer (score 0):

JSData with Angular support works amazing and shares instances between all queries - http://www.js-data.io/ + http://www.js-data.io/v1.5.8/docs/js-data-angular